# SQLite: trim usage

Tags: sqlite, trim

My goal is to extract the domain out of given URL.

For that end I use the following:

```
select distinct ltrim(rtrim('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...', '/'), 'https://')
```

The result I get is:

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```

While the following is expected:

```
www.youtube.com
```

How can the above be achieved?

***Note:***

I notices that the `trim` function works differently than I expected.

- `select distinct ltrim('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v...', 'youtu')` returns the same string without any change.
- Trying to trim only the slash by `select ltrim('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v...', '/')` returns the same string as well.

Any explainations are welcomed.

Comment: This is not how trimming works; it just removes any characters that appear somewhere in the second parameter, until it encounters one character that does not. Anyway, why do you want to do this in SQL and not in your actual programming language?

Answer (score 2):

Trim only removes the given characters at the beginning and/or end of the string. 
You'll need substr and instr. (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

But the best option is probably to fix this in your code before saving it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I didn't use trim but substr as offered.

The following worked:

```
select replace(substr(substr(<url>, instr(<url>, '//')+2),0,instr(substr(<url>, instr(<url>, '//')+2),'/')),'.','')

select replace(substr(substr(<url>, instr(<url>, '//www.')+6),0,instr(substr(<url>, instr(<url>, '//www.')+6),'/')),'.','')
```